# Extracting file name from NSData

Tags: ios

I am using bluetooth to send files along to other devices. The content sent is NSData:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myFilePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.ext", button.titleLabel.text]];

NSData *Recording = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myFilePath];
```

The file is an image. The file is received and views fine, but I would like to save it to the documents directory with the same name it had before, which is the button.titleLabel.text. When you send a file, it always has a name. How can I get it?

Comment: Send the name as a separate piece of information before or after the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your code

  ```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
  NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
  NSString *myFilePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.ext", button.titleLabel.text]];  
  NSData *Recording = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myFilePath];
  ```
- Make NSDictionary and put the filename and image data like this

  ```
  NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:myFilePath,Recording  forKeys:@"fileName",@"imageData"];
  ```
- Then convert the dictionary into NSData like this

  ```
  NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict];
  ```

---

- After recieving the data convert the data into dictionary again and extract the imageData and the filePath

  ```
  NSDictionary *myDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the filename as a separate entity (Possibly NSString or NSData) or, since it's an image, you could add the filename to the EXIF data, although that is not easy.